# Probability that one set of dice rolls is greater than or equal to a given set

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, random-variables, dice

###### Context

In tabletop roleplaying games (TTRPGs), the characters in the game usually have numeric scores tied to certain statistics. In general, these scores can be determined according to a bounded-value algorithm (e.g., one might ensure the sums of the scores for all characters are the same) or randomly according to some dice roll. It is of interest to analyze the probability involved with a dice-rolling method to compare its fairness with non-random methods.

###### Terminology

We obtain a single "score" by rolling four six-sided dice and discarding the lowest result. So, if $W$, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ all follow the discrete uniform distribution on $[1,6]$, then the score is given by: $$W + X + Y + Z - \min\{W, X, Y, Z\}.$$

We obtain an "array" by generating six scores. For example, if we roll $$\{1,3,3,5\}, \{2,2,6,6\}, \{2,4,4,5\}, \{3,4,6,6\}, \{2,2,5,6\}, \{4,5,5,6\}$$ then our array would be $\{11, 14, 13, 16, 13, 16\}$. Arrays are unordered, so, $\{11, 14, 13, 16, 13, 16\}$ is equivalent to $\{11,13,13,14,16,16\}$, for example.

###### Problem

Given some array $A$, we seek to determine the probability that generating another array, $B$, results in an array that is "as good or better" than $A$. We give two definitions of this metric and wish to calculate probabilities for both.

1. The sum of the scores in $B$ is greater than or equal to the sum of the scores in $A$.
2. There exists an ordering of the scores in $A$ and $B$, $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$, such that $\forall i, b_i \geq a_i$.

###### Attempts

###### Problem 1

For the first problem, we could disregard the structure of the array were it not for the fact that minimum rolls are dropped on a score-by-score basis: the distribution of sums for rolling $24$ dice and dropping the lowest $6$ is not *a priori* the same as the sum of scores in an array. So it would seem we need a way to model a single random variable $V \sim W + X + Y + Z - \min\{W, X, Y, Z\}$. If we can do that, then the random quantity of interest becomes a sum of six such variables, and the sum of random variables is something I am more familiar with. For example, the density function of the sum of two random variables is given by: $$f_{X_1 + X_2}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(z - y)f_{X_2}(y)dy.$$ We could then use the combined density function to calculate the probability of getting a higher value. However, I get stuck at modeling the $\min\{W, X, Y, Z\}$ component of $V$, as I am unfamiliar with combining random variables in ways other than summation.

###### Problem 2

The second problem seems even more complicated, and many of the same issues apply as did for the first problem. One thought I had was to model the comparison of $A$ and $B$ with a binomial discrete distribution (which can be interpreted as the number of success among $n$ independent trials), but issues arise considering that the probability to "beat" each score in $A$ varies based on the value of the score and because the six scores are compared all at once, rather than in pairs.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also, please indicate the source of this problem.  It looks more like a programming challenge than a math problem.

Comment: @lulu They told you the source of the problem. They said it was for a Table Top Role Playing Game (TTRPG).

Comment: To the OP (i.e. original poster): if you will pardon the pun, this is a *dicey* situation.  Under normal circumstances, it is assumed that the OP is a Math student, seeking help on a Math problem that they have encountered as part of their studies.  Then, the OP is often directed to [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) for help in influencing mathSE reviewers to react positively, rather than negatively to the question.  ...See next comment

Comment: This situation seems different, because it seems plausible to me that you are not a Math student, but have encountered a Math problem.  Unfortunately, MathSE reviewers are often inflexible, with respect to forgoing the normal protocol in such a situation.  Therefore, you are expected to provide (pardon the ambiguity) *context*.  That is, why is the question important to you.  Personally, I regard the typical MathSE reaction here as nonsensical, but MathSE doesn't belong to me.  ...see next comment

Comment: Anyway, my (personal) sole criticism is that you assumed that MathSE reviewers would immediately recognize the acronym TTRGP, which I personally had never heard of.  The comment of @MikeEarnest filled this gap.

Comment: There is a separate issue: assuming that you are totally untrained in Math, what are you looking for, as an answer to this question?  As the comment of @lulu indicated, if you are untrained in Math, then this seems like a computer programming challenge, and the question is not appropriate for this forum.  Alternatively, if you are looking for help to construct a Math formula, the problem is that this is a significantly complicated Probability problem.  ...see next comment

Comment: Personally, I would not attempt to show an answer to a *new* Probability student.  Instead, I would ask the Probability student to find the right Probability textbook for them, open it to page 1, and proceed from there.  If such an answer was to be provided for you, you would have to study Probability theory anyway, just to master the concepts that underly the answer.

Comment: What is your Math background?  Also, are you asking a computer programming question, or a Math question?

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but anydice.com calculates dice probabilities very well. This: "output 6d[highest 3 of 4d6]" without the quotes will give you the probability distribution for your first metric. The second is more difficult. You would probably want to check an anydice forum.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the feedback. I have added a "context" section and an "attempts" section to flush out the post. This *could* be a programming problem (and I might end up writing a program to approximate the probability), but I feel as though a pure mathematics answer would be more satisfying and would scale better to more general cases.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for the feedback. I have added a "context" that assumes less prior knowledge from the reader. To address what type of answer I am looking for, I am seeking a pure mathematics answer (if that makes sense). I could (and may very well) program something to approximate this probability, but that wouldn't scale well for more general cases (e.g. more scores in the array or larger dice) and would be less interesting than learning the math behind the "proper" way to calculate the result.

Comment: The first one should pose no real difficulty.  It's easy enough to get the distribution of the individual scores and that suffices.  The second, however, looks ugly as it depends (strongly) on the exact shape of the array.  That one, I would simply sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses my [Icepool Python library](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool). You can try it in your browser using [this JupyterLite notebook](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/notebooks/lab?path=ability_scores%2Fone_set_strictly_better.ipynb).

### Problem 0: 4d6 drop lowest

This is small enough for brute force enumeration of all possibilities, though more efficient algorithms do exist. More on this later.

```
import icepool

single_ability = icepool.d6.highest(4, 3)

print(single_ability)
```

Denominator: 1296

| Outcome | Weight | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 0.077160% |
| 4 | 4 | 0.308642% |
| 5 | 10 | 0.771605% |
| 6 | 21 | 1.620370% |
| 7 | 38 | 2.932099% |
| 8 | 62 | 4.783951% |
| 9 | 91 | 7.021605% |
| 10 | 122 | 9.413580% |
| 11 | 148 | 11.419753% |
| 12 | 167 | 12.885802% |
| 13 | 172 | 13.271605% |
| 14 | 160 | 12.345679% |
| 15 | 131 | 10.108025% |
| 16 | 94 | 7.253086% |
| 17 | 54 | 4.166667% |
| 18 | 21 | 1.620370% |

### Problem 1: Player A has total ability scores greater than or equal to player B

As you posted, the sum of dice can be computed using repeated convolution. From there one can simply find all of the joint outcomes, their probabilities, and choose the ones in which Player A has score greater or equal to Player B. These can be implemented as operators.

```
print(6 @ single_ability >= 6 @ single_ability)
```

Denominator: 22452257707354557240087211123792674816

| Outcome | Weight | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| False | 10773601417436608285167797336637018642 | 47.984490% |
| True | 11678656289917948954919413787155656174 | 52.015510% |

### Problem 2: There exists a pairing of ability scores such that each of Player A's scores is greater than or equal to Player B's paired score

The trick is to express the problem not over the six pairs, but the values the scores can take.
To wit: what is the chance, that for all values from 18 to 3, player A will have at least as many scores of at least that value as player B? (The equivalency is left as an exercise for the reader.)

From here, it turns out we can efficiently solve dice pool problems as long as we phrase the evaluation as
a series of iterative state transitions over tuples of (outcome, how many dice in each pool rolled that outcome)
and keep the number of states to a minimum. In this case the "dice" in the pool are entire ability scores rather than individual d6s.
[Here's an explanation of the underlying algorithm.](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool/blob/main/papers/icepool_preprint.pdf)

```
class SortedAllGe(icepool.MultisetEvaluator):
    def next_state(self, state, outcome, a, b):
        # state is how many dice A has of outcome or higher minus how many dice B has of outcome or higher,
        # but "sticks" at -1 if it ever goes negative, indicating that B had a higher paired die at some point.
        if state is None:
            state = 0
        elif state < 0:
            return -1
        state += a - b
        if state < 0:
            return -1
        else:
            return state
        
    def final_outcome(self, final_state):
        return final_state >= 0
    
    def order(self):
        # See outcomes in descending order.
        return -1
    
evaluator = SortedAllGe()
print(evaluator.evaluate(single_ability.pool(6), single_ability.pool(6)))
```

Denominator: 22452257707354557240087211123792674816

| Outcome | Weight | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| False | 17750571119832007830956108494444318705 | 79.059181% |
| True | 4701686587522549409131102629348356111 | 20.940819% |

(This is why you don't roll ability scores if you want any semblance of fairness.)

In fact, we can also formulate the problem of "roll N dice, keep the M highest" in this way. This is what underlies the `keep_highest()` method at the top. While more efficient algorithms do exist for that specific problem ([example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130025/formula-for-dropping-dice-non-brute-force)), this is still fairly fast and reduces the amount of bespoke code.

### Variant: At least one score strictly greater than

This is the chance that A's array is strictly better than B's array (and vice versa).

We can either subtract off the chance that A and B will have exactly the same sorted array, or we can explicitly encode it into the evaluation function:

```
class StrictlyBetter(icepool.MultisetEvaluator):
    def next_state(self, state, outcome, a, b):
        # This time we explicitly store whether each side had some score up on the other.
        # This increases the state space and is therefore less efficient, but is still quite fast.
        advantage, a_had_one_up, b_had_one_up = state or (0, False, False)
        advantage += a - b
        if advantage > 0:
            a_had_one_up = True
        if advantage < 0:
            b_had_one_up = True
        return advantage, a_had_one_up, b_had_one_up
        
    def final_outcome(self, final_state):
        _, a_had_one_up, b_had_one_up = final_state
        if a_had_one_up and not b_had_one_up:
            return 'a strictly better'
        elif b_had_one_up and not a_had_one_up:
            return 'b strictly better'
        elif not (a_had_one_up or b_had_one_up):
            return 'exactly the same'
        else:
            return 'mixed result'
    
    def order(self):
        # See outcomes in descending order.
        return -1
    
evaluator = StrictlyBetter()
print(evaluator.evaluate(single_ability.pool(6), single_ability.pool(6)))
```

Denominator: 22452257707354557240087211123792674816

| Outcome | Weight | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a strictly better | 4696617436843743365666704597889926627 | 20.918241% |
| b strictly better | 4696617436843743365666704597889926627 | 20.918241% |
| exactly the same | 5069150678806043464398031458429484 | 0.022577% |
| mixed result | 13053953682988264465289403896554392078 | 58.140940% |

### Miscellaneous notes

AnyDice is fine for Problem 1, but will have trouble with Problem 2 since, apart from a few built-in functions and operators, it appears to be based on exhaustive multiset enumeration.

You may also be interested in my interactive [ability score calculator](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/apps/ability_scores.html). While it doesn't solve this problem exactly it does give the distribution of raw and point-buy totals for a  variety of ability score generation methods.